# Can anyone please explain the below code on spring autowiring ? can anyone please give a link to a working example?

Tags: spring, annotations, autowired

//below is the code . I am not able to understand what is happening here . How is this working ?

```
@Configuration
public class DataSrcConfg {

 protected DS ds;

@Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
@Lazy(true)
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws SQLException {
    return new JdbcTemplate(this.ds);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way autowire by type is being used here is wrong. The code that creates your JdbcTemplate Bean doesn't have any dependencies being injected to it via Spring so the autowire by type is pointless. Do you want an example of where autowire by type would be used correctly?

Comment: Hi Adrain, thank you for the comment . Yes I would like to see an example or the correct way in which the above and be modified to . Thank You !!